# Bounds on trace of product of hermitian matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Is there any theorem which can put a bound on 
$$ Tr (V_1 V_2 \dots V_n) $$ as a function of product of $$ Tr (V_1)^{p_1} Tr (V_2)^{p_2} \dots Tr (V_n)^{p_n} $$ where $V_i$ are hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix},  \ \ W=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $$\text {Tr}\,(VW)=2, \ \ \text {Tr}\,(V)=\text {Tr}\,(W)=0.$$

Comment: No. Please see the edit.